# Why is my PHP error log lagging behind by 2 hours?

Tags: php, timezone, zend-cache

When checking php.ini, from both phpinfo and php -i on the command line, my timezone is set to Africa/Johannesburg. So my timezone is GMT +2.

I wrote a tiny snippet to check the time is right as follows:

```
echo date('h:i A', time());
echo '<br />' . ini_get('date.timezone');
```

and this outputs the correct time, matching with my localmachine's system time.

However, when I look at my php error log, the time on each error log item is behind by exactly two hours? Why is this, and how can I fix this.

Also having issues with Zend Cache, and i think this time issue is causing it.

Comment: What is your server's system time zone?

Comment: Running Wamp on Win 7 : (UTC+2:00) Harare, Pretoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like PHP is configure with one timezone, and the server it is running on is set to a different time zone (possibly GMT / UTC). This means all file operations etc will be working on a different timezone to your PHP scripts.

Check the system timezone of your server.

Comment: Could it be because PHP is using GMT and Windows 7 is using UTC?

Answer (score 0):

Google-fu: read what the [PHP official site writes](http://bugs.php.net/45191).

Comment: This is probably not it: His system time zone is set correctly.